# How to set width to Mobile screen size using HTML / CSS

Tags: android, html, css, width, screen

I am developing a website Register page.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false)
```

With the above trap, I directed the page to a separate mobile page, where the problems started with setting the width.

in the mobile page, I tried setting the width in CSS like `width="auto"`, `width=100%` and even a width element, but still the Register page occupies just 30%-40% of the screen (`used align: left`) and not visible.

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Please help me how to come out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this tag in the head tag:

```
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
```

and i advice you to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)  it will be fix every thing for you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

There is an explanation on it as wel as examples.

see: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`